# Getting "Error on executing: Secure Store can only be used with SharePoint Server." on a SP2013 list workflow on my SP Server farm

Tags: workflow, sql-server, secure-store

I have a SP workflow that runs on creation/modification of a list item. The workflow connects to an SQL Server db and executes a usp. The SQL Server credentials are stored in Secure Store.
When the workflow executes I get this error in the output. Running SP Server on my farm, not sure where this is coming from.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out so posting. I was using the iLoveSharePoint Workflow Actions for SP2010 deployed in an SP2013 environment. In the source file Helper.cs there is a check to determine the environment; this check relies on the hard coded product GUIDs for the various SP2010 versions (Server, Foundation, Enterprise, etc.). When the 2013 environment fails this check the error in my question is thrown.
This step can by bypassed by commenting out the method call.
I deployed the iLoveSharePoint Custom Workflow Activities solution because I needed to make an SQL call from within a list workflow. If you're attempting to do the same thing you'll also have to rely on a connection method other than Secure Store. Due to breaking changes in the API between 10 and 13 the code used to retrieve the credentials from Secure Store fails in SP2013. I edited the solution to allow trusted SQL connections and used Integrate Security=SSPI in my connection string: the workflow activity worked fine after that.